# Probability of Getting a "Perfect Score" in the Card Matching Game Concentration

Tags: probability, statistics, card-games

A person is playing the card matching game [concentration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_(game)). There are 40 cards, 20 pairs total. All the cards are shuffled and placed at random face down. A *turn* consists of two *moves* and a move is simply turning a card face up to see what it is. If both cards are matched during a *turn* they are removed form the game and the turn total goes up by one. If the cards are not matched they are returned to the face down position and again, the turn total goes up by one.

**My questions:**

**1.** What is the probability of getting a perfect score (20 *turns*) in a game of concentration?

**2.** How do you go about finding this probability?

Comment: You could have written the entire question in about 3 sentences (so you might wanna do it, unless you're hoping to wear-out your readers)...

Comment: I can put the question first and then move the rules underneath? I wanted to be thorough because last time I asked a question (different exchange site) I got ridiculed for not being thorough enough (even though that question was rather thorough to being with).

Comment: I mean like, you don't have to mention every details 3 times, and you can certainly remove obvious assumptions like "the player is not cheating". You could have just as well said that the player is not psychic (does not own any unnatural forces).

Comment: You know I could have,last time I asked a question on superuser I faced comments by a high ranking user who was befuddled by a simple question (that was eventually answered). The user asking for more and more clarifications and details. I had initially thought I wrote a thorough and accurate question too, but it somehow was "confusing" and not detailed enough. I was trying to avoid that kind of situation here, so I just put in as much detail as possible and I tried to do it in a neat and organized way. But I guess every time I ask a question I do something wrong.

Comment: +1 well explained question. Your last assumption seems wrong to me. Are you aware of binomal coef.? From brief review of the game and question, it seems to me as if each time you need to choose 2 of the remaining cards, and the probability that both are the same is $1/remaining-cards^2$.

Comment: Isn't the answer just $1*3*5*...*39$?

Comment: @Ragnar: No, it's the reciprocal of it.

Comment: @barak: I re-wrote the question in 6 sentences $-$ see below.

Comment: Shortened it. :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at a prefect game. In each turn, we will flip one of the cards and after we've seen it, we will flip the other one, so the second (fourth, sixth...) choice of cards depend on the choice of the first (third, fifth...) card.

Since there is 1 in 39 cards to complete the pair once we've selected the first card, there is a chance of $\frac{1}{39}$ of pairing the first two cards.

Once that is done, we are left with 38 cards, so if we flip one up, there is a chance of $\frac{1}{37}$ to complete the secong pair.

...

Once we arrive to the last pair of cards, if we flip one of them up, there will be just one remaining card so the chance of completeing the last pair is $\frac{1}{1}$.

So the chance of a perfect game is:

$$\prod_{k=1}^{20}\frac{1}{2k-1} = \frac{1}{319830986772877770815625} \simeq 3.12·10^{-24}$$

Answer (score 0):

On this site, the following description of your question would suffice:

A person is playing the card matching game [concentration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_(game)). There are 40 cards, consisting of 20 matched pairs. Initially all 40 cards are dealt, at random, face down on the table. A *turn* consists of turning over two cards: if the two cards match, they are discarded; otherwise, they are turned face down again and left on the table. The game ends when no cards are left on the table.

What is the probability of a perfect game, i.e. a game that lasts exactly 20 turns?